# C# dll registration with regasm warning RA0000

Tags: c#, delphi, dll, regasm

I have C# dll and want to use it in my delphi code, before that the dll must be registered with regasm. I have been trying to register this dll but constatntly getting below warning-

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>regasm c:\debug\modbusdll.dll
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Assembly Registration Utility 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1998-2004.  All rights reserved.

RegAsm : warning RA0000 : No types were registered


C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>
```

On the internet I found that COMVisible set to be true in AssemblyInfo.cs, and it will solve this problem.But it was already set to true and still I am getting this problem.

C# code is as follows-

namespace ModbusDLL
{
    //// {0E32E465-79A4-4251-AF02-FEBE05198F76}

```
[Guid("0E32E465-79A4-4251-AF02-FEBE05198F76")]
public interface IModbus
{
    bool setABC(int a);//{GUID:f7f14b6f-e8da-4562-baf7-aa6846861f66}
    byte[] getDiscreteInput(ushort id, byte unit, ushort startaddress, ushort numinputs);//{GUID:f7f14b6f-e8da-4562-baf7-aa6846861f67}
    byte[] getInputRegister(ushort id, byte unit, ushort startaddress, ushort numinputs);//{GUID:f7f14b6f-e8da-4562-baf7-aa6846861f68}
    byte[] getHoldingRegister(ushort id, byte unit, ushort startaddress, ushort numinputs);//{GUID:f7f14b6f-e8da-4562-baf7-aa6846861f69}
}
 [Guid("0E32E465-79A4-4251-AF02-FEBE05198F77")]
public class ModbusImplementor:IModbus
{
     ModbusTcpClient m=null;
     public ModbusImplementor()
     {
         //m = new ModbusTcpClient(ip, port);
     }

     /*public ModbusImplementor(string ip, ushort port)
     {
         m = new ModbusTcpClient(ip, port);
     }*/
    public bool setABC(int a)
    {
        int A = a;
        return true;
    }

    public byte[] getDiscreteInput(ushort id, byte unit, ushort startaddress, ushort numinputs)
    {
        //2,
        byte[] values =new byte[15]; 
        m.ReadDiscreteInputs(id, unit, startaddress, numinputs, ref values);
        return values;
    }
    public byte[] getInputRegister(ushort id, byte unit, ushort startaddress, ushort numinputs)
    {
        byte[] values = new byte[15]; 
        m.ReadInputRegister(id, unit, startaddress, numinputs, ref values);
        return values;
    }

    public byte[] getHoldingRegister(ushort id, byte unit, ushort startaddress, ushort numinputs)
    {
        byte[] values = new byte[15]; 
        m.ReadHoldingRegister(id, unit, startaddress, numinputs, ref values);
        return values;
    }

    ~ ModbusImplementor()
    {
        m.Disconnect();
        m.Dispose();
    }


}
```

}

AssemblyInfo.cs-

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following 
// set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
// associated with an assembly.
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("ModbusDLL")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Microsoft")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("ModbusDLL")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © Microsoft 2016")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]

// Setting ComVisible to false makes the types in this assembly not visible 
// to COM components.  If you need to access a type in this assembly from 
// COM, set the ComVisible attribute to true on that type.
[assembly: ComVisible(true)]

// The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM
[assembly: Guid("f7f14b6f-e8da-4562-baf7-aa6846861f66")]

// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Comment: That solution tells that class should have default constructor, that I already have. still having the same issue @Reazon

Comment: @PriyankaMehta have you tried using the `Codebase` option? Try registering it with this switch and see...